# Need to plot the support and resistance @ all relevant candles, but it is only plotting at crossover

Tags: plot, pine-script

I want to plot a support at all candles when the price crosses above the previous quarter high and previous month high, and then crosses down the previous week **low**, the close becomes a support. 
As long as the price stays then below the previous week **high**, each close becomes a support. The condition remains as long as the prices do not cross below previous quarter low **OR** previous month low, then support also stops. It now only plots at the crossover.

For resistance it is the opposite.
[image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT8Iy.jpg)

```
//@version=3 
//By Juros
//-------------------------------
// support
// If the price crosses above the previous quarter high and previous month high, and then crosses down the previous week low, the close becomes a support. 
//As long as the price stays then below the previous week high, each close becomes a support. The    condition remains as long as the prices do not cross 
//below previous quarter low OR previous month low, then support also stops.

//-------------------------------
// resistance
// If the price crosses below the previous quarter low and previous month low, and then crosses up the previous week high, the close becomes a resistance.
// As long as the price stays then above the previous week low, each close becomes a support.  The condition remains as long as the price does not cross
// above previous quarter high OR previous month high, then resistance also stops.


study(title="Universal support and resistance", shorttitle="Univ sup & res", overlay=true, precision=8)
prevwkH = input(true, title="Show previous week high?")
prevwkL = input(true, title="show previous week low?")

//previous week
prevWeekHigh = security(tickerid, 'W', high[1], lookahead=true)
prevWeekLow = security(tickerid, 'W', low[1], lookahead=true)

//previous Week Plots
plot(prevwkH and prevWeekHigh ? prevWeekHigh : na, title="Prev Week High", style=stepline,   linewidth=1, color=green,transp=20)
plot(prevwkL and prevWeekLow ? prevWeekLow : na, title="Prev Week Low", style=stepline, linewidth=1, color=green,transp=20)

// alerts
Buy = close > prevWeekHigh
Sell = close < prevWeekLow

Buyposmemo = false
Buyposmemo := Buy ? true : Sell ? false : Buyposmemo[1]
Buynow = Buy and not (Buyposmemo[1])
bgcolor(Buynow ?  color(green, 90) :na)

Sellposmemo = false
Sellposmemo := Sell ? true : Buy ? false : Sellposmemo[1]
Sellnow = Sell and not (Sellposmemo[1])
bgcolor(Sellnow ?  color(red, 90) :na)

alertcondition(Buy, title = "Buy now", message="buy now")
alertcondition(Sell, title = "Sell now", message="Sell now")

//-------------------------------------------------------------

//universal trend line
prevQuarterHigh = security(tickerid, '3M', high[1], lookahead=true)
prevQuarterLow = security(tickerid, '3M', low[1], lookahead=true)

upTrend = false
upTrend := (not upTrend[1] and crossover(close, prevQuarterHigh)) or (upTrend[1] and not    crossunder(close, prevQuarterLow))

//-------------------------------------------------------------

//plot support & resistance 
plot (upTrend and crossunder(close, prevWeekLow) ? low-(high-low+1) : na, style=circles,    color=green, transp=0, linewidth=4 )
plot (not upTrend and crossover(close, prevWeekHigh) ? high+(high-low+1) : na, style=circles,   color=red, transp=0, linewidth=4 )
```

Comment: Can you add an image that shows the problem and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello Baris, just added an image. Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I have problems, I always clone my code with `study(overlay=false)` and plot some of the signals that I suspect causing the problems.

So, in your case, you can copy&paste your code to a new indicator and add the following lines at the end. Please delete all other `plot()` functions. Otherwise, you will have scaling issues and the result won't be that visible.

```
//plot support & resistance 
plot(series=upTrend ? 1:0, color=color.orange)
plot(series=crossunder(close, prevWeekLow) ? 1:0, color=color.green)
plot(series=crossover(close, prevWeekHigh) ? 1:0, color=color.red)
```

This is the result:

[image]

If you look closely, the problem here is that `crossover()` and `crossunder()` functions return a `BOOL` value only when the crossover/crossunder happens. Therefore, your condition in the plot function becomes `TRUE` for one bar only.

What you need to do is figure out how you can keep a signal `TRUE` for crossover/crossunder until the opposite signal is encountered.

To do this, I suggest you start using `v4`. Then you can use the `var` keyword. Variables created with the `var` keyword hold their values until you overwrite them. So, you can do the following:

```
var isSupport = false
var isResistance = false 

if (crossunder(close, prevWeekLow))
    isSupport := true
    isResistance := false

if (crossover(close, prevWeekHigh))
    isSupport := false
    isResistance := true
```

Here is the full code using `v4`:

```
//@version=4
//By Juros
//-------------------------------
// support
// If the price crosses above the previous quarter high and previous month high, and then crosses down the previous week low, the close becomes a support. 
//As long as the price stays then below the previous week high, each close becomes a support. The    condition remains as long as the prices do not cross 
//below previous quarter low OR previous month low, then support also stops.

//-------------------------------
// resistance
// If the price crosses below the previous quarter low and previous month low, and then crosses up the previous week high, the close becomes a resistance.
// As long as the price stays then above the previous week low, each close becomes a support.  The condition remains as long as the price does not cross
// above previous quarter high OR previous month high, then resistance also stops.


study(title="Universal support and resistance", shorttitle="Univ sup & res", overlay=true, precision=8)
prevwkH = input(true, title="Show previous week high?")
prevwkL = input(true, title="show previous week low?")

//previous week
prevWeekHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', high[1], lookahead=true)
prevWeekLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, 'W', low[1], lookahead=true)

//previous Week Plots
plot(prevwkH and prevWeekHigh ? prevWeekHigh : na, title="Prev Week High", style=plot.style_stepline,   linewidth=1, color=color.green,transp=20)
plot(prevwkL and prevWeekLow ? prevWeekLow : na, title="Prev Week Low", style=plot.style_stepline, linewidth=1, color=color.green,transp=20)

// alerts
Buy = close > prevWeekHigh
Sell = close < prevWeekLow

Buyposmemo = false
Buyposmemo := Buy ? true : Sell ? false : Buyposmemo[1]
Buynow = Buy and not (Buyposmemo[1])
bgcolor(Buynow ?  color(color.green) :na)

Sellposmemo = false
Sellposmemo := Sell ? true : Buy ? false : Sellposmemo[1]
Sellnow = Sell and not (Sellposmemo[1])
bgcolor(Sellnow ?  color(color.red) :na)

alertcondition(Buy, title = "Buy now", message="buy now")
alertcondition(Sell, title = "Sell now", message="Sell now")

//-------------------------------------------------------------

//universal trend line
prevQuarterHigh = security(syminfo.tickerid, '3M', high[1], lookahead=true)
prevQuarterLow = security(syminfo.tickerid, '3M', low[1], lookahead=true)

upTrend = false
upTrend := (not upTrend[1] and crossover(close, prevQuarterHigh)) or (upTrend[1] and not    crossunder(close, prevQuarterLow))

//-------------------------------------------------------------
var isSupport = false
var isResistance = false 

if (crossunder(close, prevWeekLow))
    isSupport := true
    isResistance := false

if (crossover(close, prevWeekHigh))
    isSupport := false
    isResistance := true

//plot support & resistance 
plot (upTrend and isSupport ? low-(high-low+1) : na, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.green, transp=0, linewidth=4 )
plot (not upTrend and isResistance ? high+(high-low+1) : na, style=plot.style_circles, color=color.red, transp=0, linewidth=4 )
```

[image]

Note that in the image above, the below indicator (debug one) still has your code. So you can kinda compare.

Comment: Tnx very much Very good tip about plotting it with overlay=false to see what is wrong!

Comment: Glad I was able to help. You can read [this](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#debugging) to know more about debugging in pinescript.